# Directly assign URL to a has_attachment after direct upload

Tags: rails-activestorage

I am able to generate a presigned URL for direct upload from an iOS app.  I want to set the ActiveStorage attachment URL directly, based on this presigned one.  That way, rails doesn't deal with processing the upload data.  I cannot seem to find a canonical approach to this.  I tried setting `key` directly, but that's an attribute of the attachment blob.

```rb
    @photo = @field_note.photos.new(key: "field_notes/#{@field_note.uuid}/photos/#{photo_params[:filename]}")
    @presigned_url = AwsBucketAccessor.bucket.presigned_post(
      key: @photo.key,
      success_action_status: "201",
      signature_expiration: (Time.now.utc + 15.minutes)
    )
    render(:show) && return if @photo.save
```